# EditText view not expanding on new line

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to get user comment and after pressing the enter button, the text just gets hide due to a line change. I
m trying to expand my EditText View so that I can show at least 4 lines of comment.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/comments_body_box"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comments_text_body"
        android:layout_width="151dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxLength="2000"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/comment_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Above is my current code, can someone tell me what's wrong with my XML file?

I added the following two attributes too

```
android:maxLength="2000"
android:maxLines="4"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this into your EditText attribute

```
  android:lines="4"
```

Also, set height to **wrap_content**

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Thanks you @john, this fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 2):

First I cleaned up your code

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/comments_body_box"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:background="#fff"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:gravity="right"
android:maxHeight="150dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="10"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/comments_text_body"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:maxLength="2000"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/comment_send"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="12dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp" />
```

1) You should use **layout_width="0dp"** as you use **layout_weight** in the LinearLayout

2) do **NOT** use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" as it doesn't make sense in the LinearLayout

3) And use layout_height="wrap_content" is the EditText

Comment: Thank you @Alexei, the thing is this whole layout was inside a swipeRefreshLayout and that's the reason I added all that extra attributes.
layout_height="wrap_content" fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the `EditText` set to `match_parent`.

Try changing
`android:layout_height="match_parent"`
to
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

Before starting, you need to make a few changes to your code.

1. If you are using `android:layout_weight` attribute, you should always set your width attribute as `android:layout_width="0dp"`
2. Since you are using a LinearLayout remove the attributes `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_alignParentEnd`. They are invalid for this case.
3. Since you are using an `ImageView` under the `EditText`, it would be better if you assigned a height to your view instead of `match_parent`, or just use `wrap_content` if you don't need a fixed size.

You mentioned you needed to display at least 4 lines of text in your `EditText`. If that is required for all use cases, add the attribute `android:minLines="4"` to your `EditText`. If you want a maximum of 4 lines to be displayed, then your code `android:maxLines="4"` works perfectly.

To prevent the issue where the text gets hidden as the number of lines increases, add the attribute `android:scrollbars="vertical"` to the `EditText`.

Your final EditText XML may look something like (assuming 4 lines are needed at a minimum. If not, just remove the `android:minLines` attribute)

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/comments_text_body"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:minLength="2000"
            android:minLines="4"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp" />
```